# Deployment of Smart Contracts with Azure Ethereum Consortium does not work

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, mining, contract-deployment, microsoft-azure

I created an Azure Ethereum Consortium. The Ethereum Network deployed has 2 Transaction Nodes behind a load balancer. Via Putty I connect to one of the transaction nodes.

Then I enter

```
geth attach
```

Now the console is open. The solidity compiler is installed. Then I unlock the account to be used:

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[1], "{your password}");
```

The balance of the account is:

```
400000000000000000000
```

Then I compile the code:

```
var greeterSource = 'pragma solidity ^0.4.9; /** @title Mortal.*/ contract mortal { /* Define variable owner of the type address*/ address owner; /**@dev this function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract. */ function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } /**@dev Function to recover the funds on the contract. */ function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) { selfdestruct(owner); } } } /** @title Greeter.*/ contract greeter is mortal { /* define variable greeting of the type string */ string greeting; /**@dev This function runs when the contract is executed. * @param _greeting Greeting message. */ function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } /* main function */ /**@dev This function returns the greeting message. * @return greeting The greeting message. */ function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }';

var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource);
```

The result:

```
{
  <stdin>:greeter: {
    code: "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",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      compilerOptions: "--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize",
      compilerVersion: "0.4.9",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {...},
        title: "Greeter."
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.4.9",
      source: "pragma solidity ^0.4.9; /** @title Mortal.*/ contract mortal { /* Define variable owner of the type address*/ address owner; /**@dev this function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract. */ function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } /**@dev Function to recover the funds on the contract. */ function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) { selfdestruct(owner); } } } /** @title Greeter.*/ contract greeter is mortal { /* define variable greeting of the type string */ string greeting; /**@dev This function runs when the contract is executed. * @param _greeting Greeting message. */ function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } /* main function */ /**@dev This function returns the greeting message. * @return greeting The greeting message. */ function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  },
  <stdin>:mortal: {
    code: "0x6060604052341561000c57fe5b5b60008054600160a060020a03191633600160a060020a03161790555b5b609c806100386000396000f300606060405263ffffffff60e060020a60003504166341c0e1b581146020575bfe5b3415602757fe5b602d602f565b005b6000543373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff90811691161415606d5760005473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16ff5b5b5600a165627a7a723058200a9fb13e0c7088d8b8834e9dacd090047f7173bbd4b22b8a2c06a00681b5631d0029",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}, {...}],
      compilerOptions: "--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize",
      compilerVersion: "0.4.9",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {...},
        title: "Mortal."
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.4.9",
      source: "pragma solidity ^0.4.9; /** @title Mortal.*/ contract mortal { /* Define variable owner of the type address*/ address owner; /**@dev this function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract. */ function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } /**@dev Function to recover the funds on the contract. */ function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) { selfdestruct(owner); } } } /** @title Greeter.*/ contract greeter is mortal { /* define variable greeting of the type string */ string greeting; /**@dev This function runs when the contract is executed. * @param _greeting Greeting message. */ function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } /* main function */ /**@dev This function returns the greeting message. * @return greeting The greeting message. */ function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I define the input variable:

```
var _greeting = "Hello World!";
```

Then I create the contract:

```
var greeterContract = web3.eth.contract(greeterCompiled["<stdin>:greeter"].info.abiDefinition);
```

The result is:

```
    {
  <stdin>:greeter: {
    code: "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",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      compilerOptions: "--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize",
      compilerVersion: "0.4.9",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {...},
        title: "Greeter."
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.4.9",
      source: "pragma solidity ^0.4.9; /** @title Mortal.*/ contract mortal { /* Define variable owner of the type address*/ address owner; /**@dev this function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract. */ function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } /**@dev Function to recover the funds on the contract. */ function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) { selfdestruct(owner); } } } /** @title Greeter.*/ contract greeter is mortal { /* define variable greeting of the type string */ string greeting; /**@dev This function runs when the contract is executed. * @param _greeting Greeting message. */ function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } /* main function */ /**@dev This function returns the greeting message. * @return greeting The greeting message. */ function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  },
  <stdin>:mortal: {
    code: "0x6060604052341561000c57fe5b5b60008054600160a060020a03191633600160a060020a03161790555b5b609c806100386000396000f300606060405263ffffffff60e060020a60003504166341c0e1b581146020575bfe5b3415602757fe5b602d602f565b005b6000543373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff90811691161415606d5760005473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16ff5b5b5600a165627a7a723058200a9fb13e0c7088d8b8834e9dacd090047f7173bbd4b22b8a2c06a00681b5631d0029",
    info: {
      abiDefinition: [{...}, {...}],
      compilerOptions: "--combined-json bin,abi,userdoc,devdoc --add-std --optimize",
      compilerVersion: "0.4.9",
      developerDoc: {
        methods: {...},
        title: "Mortal."
      },
      language: "Solidity",
      languageVersion: "0.4.9",
      source: "pragma solidity ^0.4.9; /** @title Mortal.*/ contract mortal { /* Define variable owner of the type address*/ address owner; /**@dev this function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract. */ function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } /**@dev Function to recover the funds on the contract. */ function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) { selfdestruct(owner); } } } /** @title Greeter.*/ contract greeter is mortal { /* define variable greeting of the type string */ string greeting; /**@dev This function runs when the contract is executed. * @param _greeting Greeting message. */ function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } /* main function */ /**@dev This function returns the greeting message. * @return greeting The greeting message. */ function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }",
      userDoc: {
        methods: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
> ^C
> var _greeting = "Hello World!";
undefined
> var greeterContract = web3.eth.contract(greeterCompiled["<stdin>:greeter"].info.abiDefinition);
undefined
> greeterContract
{
  abi: [{
      constant: false,
      inputs: [],
      name: "kill",
      outputs: [],
      payable: false,
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "greet",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      type: "function"
  }, {
      inputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      type: "constructor"
  }],
  eth: {
    accounts: ["0xd44470753171e1b22dc9e5ffd9ac50e0427f49ca", "0x7dc65a6db5de74ace26ab27dd822dab0fcb36851"],
    blockNumber: 15544,
    coinbase: "0xd44470753171e1b22dc9e5ffd9ac50e0427f49ca",
    compile: {
      lll: function(),
      serpent: function(),
      solidity: function()
    },
    defaultAccount: undefined,
    defaultBlock: "latest",
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    hashrate: 0,
    mining: false,
    pendingTransactions: [],
    protocolVersion: "0x3f",
    syncing: false,
    call: function(),
    contract: function(abi),
    estimateGas: function(),
    filter: function(fil, callback),
    getAccounts: function(callback),
    getBalance: function(),
    getBlock: function(),
    getBlockNumber: function(callback),
    getBlockTransactionCount: function(),
    getBlockUncleCount: function(),
    getCode: function(),
    getCoinbase: function(callback),
    getCompilers: function(),
    getGasPrice: function(callback),
    getHashrate: function(callback),
    getMining: function(callback),
    getPendingTransactions: function(callback),
    getProtocolVersion: function(callback),
    getRawTransaction: function(),
    getRawTransactionFromBlock: function(),
    getStorageAt: function(),
    getSyncing: function(callback),
    getTransaction: function(),
    getTransactionCount: function(),
    getTransactionFromBlock: function(),
    getTransactionReceipt: function(),
    getUncle: function(),
    getWork: function(),
    iban: function(iban),
    icapNamereg: function(),
    isSyncing: function(callback),
    namereg: function(),
    resend: function(),
    sendIBANTransaction: function(),
    sendRawTransaction: function(),
    sendTransaction: function(),
    sign: function(),
    signTransaction: function(),
    submitTransaction: function(),
    submitWork: function()
  },
  at: function(address, callback),
  getData: function(),
  new: function()
}
```

Now I want to deploy the contract:

```
var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:web3.eth.accounts[1], data: greeterCompiled["<stdin>:greeter"].code, gas: 45000000000}, function(e, contract){ if(!e) { if(!contract.address) { console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined..."); } else { console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address); console.log(contract); } } })
```

The result is:

```
    {
  abi: [{
      constant: false,
      inputs: [],
      name: "kill",
      outputs: [],
      payable: false,
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "greet",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      type: "function"
  }, {
      inputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      type: "constructor"
  }],
  address: undefined,
  transactionHash: null
}
```

As you see there should be enough Gas included. But then nothing happens and no address will be assigned. Also the balance of the account remains the same. Am I not connected properly (when I run admin.peers I see all the other connected nodes) or what could be the problem?

Comment: wait a bit longer - callback should be called once more with instance address.

Comment: I waited now for one hour and nothing happens... There was no callback and no log at all -> only undefined as immediate output and then I was able to use the console immediately afterwards again. What could be the problem?

Comment: It's a private network? Are there any mining nodes in it?

Comment: Yes, it is a private network deployed on Azure (via a template that is available there). There are mining nodes and they are running.

Comment: Eh, I'm affraid that my knowledge is to little to help you :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a solution (thanks to colleague who helped me figuring this out :) but it is somehow unsatisfying as I don't know exactly why it works now and not before.

My colleague used a different gas value (1000000 instead of 45000000000) and had to remove the `web3` from `var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:web3.eth.accounts[1], ...`

I just had to change the gas value but can use `web3`...

So the code that works now for me looks as follows:

```
var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:web3.eth.accounts[1], data: greeterCompiled["<stdin>:greeter"].code, gas: 1000000}, function(e, contract){
    if(!e) {
        if(!contract.address) {
            console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
            console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
            console.log(contract);
        }
    }
})
```

and for my colleague

```
var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:eth.accounts[1], data: greeterCompiled["<stdin>:greeter"].code, gas: 1000000}, function(e, contract){
    if(!e) {
        if(!contract.address) {
            console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
        } else {
            console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
            console.log(contract);
        }
    }
})
```